# Should I Return None or (None, None)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, coding-style

We have a object method that returns a city/state tuple, i.e. `('Boston', 'MA')`. Under some valid circumstances, there is no valid city/state to return. Stylistically, does it make more sense to return `None`, or a two element tuple containing `(None, None)` in that case?

Comment: Why not raise a `ValueError` in stead?

Comment: If the situation is valid as he states, why would you raise an error?

Comment: It's perfectly valid to stop iterating over a list, yet internally the iterator will raise `StopIteration` to flag this condition. I find exceptions are not as exceptional as their name would imply in many cases. He could just as well do `class NoCityFound(exception): pass`

Comment: If you return a `namedtuple`, the users of your functions won't have to unpack the result, and returning `None` might work as the better choice.

Comment: @multipleinterfaces: The difference between `ValueError` and `StopIteration` is that the former is, like its name says, an error, while the latter isn't.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I would return `None`. If there is no result, why return something that *looks* like a result?

It is also easier to test:

```
result = getCity()
if result:
   # do something
```

I would only return `(None, None)` if it were possible that only one of the two values is `None` (i.e. `('Boston', None)`). It would be more consistent in this case.

Comment: +1 I'd probably do a tuple-unpacking assignment (`city, state = getTuple(...)`) wrapped in a try/catch. This seems to me consistent with python philosophy: try, not test. Also, this way the call site can choose between treating this as an exceptional situation requiring exception or not.

Comment: @liori, relying on exceptions is indeed another nice python idiom, but then I would second @multipleinterfaces' comment: why not raising a `ValueError` from the function instead of having the caller stumble on a `TypeError` raised from its own code?

Comment: Because returning None will break tuple unpacking.

Comment: @Ethan, yup, that was the point of my answer. Returning `None` will raise `TypeError` *from the caller's code* if it uses the tuple unpacking idiom, which it might legitimately do if it never encountered an exceptional situation during tests, since the function is supposed to return a tuple in the first place. Even when relying on exceptions for flow control (which is arguably encouraged in Python), in this situation I'd still care about my caller and at least raise the exception from my own code.

Comment: I'm not a fan of wrapping it in a `try`/`except` because, by python standards, it adds a bulky amount of code: 2 lines for `try` and `except`, and at least three lines within the except - 1 for checking the type of exception, 1 for passing the exception up, and 1 for the failure state. That's 5 lines for some pretty simple code.

Comment: Using exceptions could hide some other problem in rare cases. I would do this instead: `city, state = getCityStateTuple("something") or (None, None)`

Answer (score 47):

By only returning one value in exceptional circumstances, you risk breaking the tuple unpacking idiom. Some of your callers might issue:

```
city, state = getCityStateTuple("something")
```

In that case, returning `None` will break *the caller* with the error:

`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

So, I personally would return `(None, None)` in your situation. Then again, your mileage may vary, and it depends on the pattern used by your callers.

Comment: This is _good_, not bad. Is it better for them to have to check then for a valid city / state, or to need to wrap that in a `try` / `except`?

Comment: How about this? `city, state = getCityStateTuple("something") or (None, None)`

Answer (score 12):

`(None, None)` does not evaluate to `False` in Python. In addition, building a tuple requires more work than, well, not building a tuple. So I would prefer `None`.

Answer (score 11):

As others have noted, a tuple with items in it does not test as `False`, which is one reason you might want to return `None` rather than `(None, None)`. However, it is possible to write a tuple *subclass* that tests as `False` even when it has items in it by overriding its `__nonzero__()` method.

```
class falsetuple(tuple):
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False
```

Then you could return `falsetuple((None, None))` when there is no value available. In fact, you could always return the *same* `falsetuple`.

I'm not necessarily recommending that you do this, in fact I have serious misgivings about flouting this convention, I'm just saying that the truthiness of non-empty tuples is not necessarily in itself a reason to not return a tuple.

Answer (score 6):

If your routine normally returns a tuple, then a tuple is what it should keep returning.  The real choice is between returning `(None, None)`, or raising an exception, and we don't have enough information to offer good advice on that.

If it were me, and I chose the tuple over the exception, I would go with the FalseTuple that kindall suggests, and also realize that the calling code (which is using tuple unpacking) can also test

```
if city is None:
```

to see if a valid result was obtained.  This way you are supporting tuple extraction across all possible return values, and still allowing the pythonic idiom of asking the object, "Do you evaluate as True?"  (Here is kindall's again for completeness):

```
class FalseTuple(tuple):
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False
```

Answer (score 4):

why not making State a property of City? That way your function would return always one value: a City or None.

Returning (None, None) is bad for all the reasons stated in the other answers and serves only to support tuple unpacking.

None is the best value to return to state that no valid city can be returned, but having a function returning 1 or 2 values is not that good, again because of tuple unpacking.

Answer (score 2):

To me, returning (None, None) would imply that (None, State) or (City, None) would also be valid return values.
If that is the case, go with (None, None), otherwise, Felix and Brent provide very good arguments for simply returning None.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement a public method for object that returned, let say `isValidLocation()` that returns true if location is valid and false if location is none.

Answer (score 1):

If you return None, it will be much easier for you to check the return value.